# Pandas datetime format to prevent NaT

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I am reading in an excel file into python with pandas.

xls = pd.ExcelFile("filename.xlsx")

df = xls.parse('Sheet1')

I have a column in my dataframe (time_since_illness_onset) with datetime objects of the form:

1900-01-03 00:00:00
1900-01-04 04:30:00

I would like to parse these so that I have a column for days, hours and seconds (the year and month here is meaningless).

I had used the following code:

```
df['time_since_illness_onset'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_since_illness_onset'], errors='coerce')
df['time_since_illness_onset'] = df['time_since_illness_onset'].dt.day + df['time_since_illness_onset'].dt.hour/24. + df['time_since_illness_onset'].dt.minute/60./24
```

It seemed to work fine. However, I noticed that for datetimes that are less than one day the above code turns the dates into NaT.

As an example, I had a row in the original dataframe like this:
22:00:00
And after I manipulated the dataframe with the two lines above it turned into a NaT. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify format of parsed datetimes and then use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) for replace `NaT` by default datetimes parsed without specifying format:

```
print (df)
  time_since_illness_onset
0      1900-01-03 00:00:00
1      1900-01-04 04:30:00
2                 22:00:00

a = pd.to_datetime(df['time_since_illness_onset'], errors='coerce')
b = pd.to_datetime(df['time_since_illness_onset'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
c = b.combine_first(a)
print (a)
0   1900-01-03 00:00:00
1   1900-01-04 04:30:00
2   2018-01-26 22:00:00
Name: time_since_illness_onset, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (b)
0                   NaT
1                   NaT
2   1900-01-01 22:00:00
Name: time_since_illness_onset, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (c)
0   1900-01-03 00:00:00
1   1900-01-04 04:30:00
2   1900-01-01 22:00:00
Name: time_since_illness_onset, dtype: datetime64[ns]

s = c.dt.day + c.dt.hour/24. + c.dt.minute/60./24
#if format HH:MM:SS one default day is necessary substract
df['time_since_illness_onset_new'] = s.where(b.isnull(), s - 1)
print (df)
  time_since_illness_onset  time_since_illness_onset_new
0      1900-01-03 00:00:00                      3.000000
1      1900-01-04 04:30:00                      4.187500
2                 22:00:00                      0.916667
```

Comment: Thank you! However, not the time is encoded incorrectly. The "time_since_illness_onset_new" for 22:00:00 should 0.91667. How do I do this most efficiently? Thanks!